# Android and iOS apps doesnt launch anymore in appcelerator Studio

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

Well, this is weird, yesterday i was working normally, and today nothing works.
When i try to run my apps i get this

**iOS**

```
[INFO] :   Launching iOS Simulator
[LiveView] version 1.0.9
[LiveView] File Server Started on Port 8324
[LiveView] Event Server Started on Port 8323
[LiveView] Client connected
[INFO] :   [LiveView] Error Evaluating app @ Line: 3
[ERROR] :  SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'var'. Expected ';' after var declaration.
[ERROR] :  File: app
[ERROR] :  Line: 3
[ERROR] :  SourceId: <null>
[ERROR] :  Backtrace:
[ERROR] :   undefined
[LiveView] Client disconnected
```

**Android**

```
[WARN] :   EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
[INFO] :   [LiveView] Error Evaluating app @ Line: undefined
[ERROR] :  SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
[ERROR] :  File: app
[ERROR] :  Line: undefined
[ERROR] :  SourceId: undefined
[ERROR] :  Backtrace:
[ERROR] :  undefined
[WARN] :   TiVerify: (Timer-0) [5000,5000] Verifying module licenses...
[INFO] :   TiVerify: (Timer-0) [436,5436] Succesfully verified module licenses
```

Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.5.0.201602170821
SDK 5.2.0. GA

Any help will be apretate..
thanks in advance..

Comment: You have av error ! , Can you disabled `liveview` and run the app again

Comment: you are right! i must activate it accidentally.. Can you reply as an answer so i can mark it ?

Comment: I will create an naswer  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you disabled `liveview` and run the app again